# Choice of semaphores, mutexes and condition variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, producer-consumer

I have a producer thread and a consumer thread, with the producer being real-time and determinism-sensitive.

Hence I decided to hoist the processing out of the producer thread into a consumer thread, using a lock-free fifo queue. The goal is to have the consumer being both responsive but also avoiding busy-waiting, while never delaying the producer for a indeterminate amount of time; thus any allocations/locks (and kernel entries, I suppose?) etc. are completely out of the question.

I've implemented this pattern, which seems to work well, however I'm unsure of why a mutex is needed at all:

```
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;

void consumer()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    while (1)
    {
        cv.wait(lock);
        // process consumation...
    }
}

void producer()
{
    while (1)
    {
        // produce and post..
        cv.notify_one();
    }
}
```

The other canonical examples seems to lock the mutex in the producer as well, why? My data communication is already thread-safe, so this shouldn't be needed. Also, is this susceptible to missing signals?

And while researching this, I stumble upon semaphores which seem to be used explicitly for this situation. What are the benefits versus this system? I prefer my solution currently, just because it is a part of the standard library.

Comment: Quite the opposite to missing signals, this is also susceptible to *spurious wakeups*. Don't forget, condition variables aren't "state"; they're only a signalling mechanism that communicate state has *changed*. The state is managed in separate data storage variables that *you* provide, and most importantly, that *you* protect with the mutex of a mutex-cv pairing. That check, as well as any modifications to your state variables, is done only while the mutex is *locked*.

Comment: I considered the spurious wakeups, but in this case they are no problem because the consumer itself will never succeed popping the queue unless something is there, thus it will go directly to sleep again (?). I can add a check on the wait, but I see it redundant.

As said, the *state* being the queue is concurrently thread-safe, so I don't see why i need to protect it with a mutex.

But the way you phrased it, you seemed to say that this is susceptible to missing signals. How can this happen?

Comment: The missed signal I referred to (and I believed you were questioning) happens when a `notify_one` takes place and there are no active waiters on the cvar. Since you're providing no predicate, the only thing that can break that wait is a notification arriving *while someone is waiting*. Otherwise it will be lost. [see trivial example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec25432b1c2c7c76).

Comment: Okay, I see it now. I guess I somehow thought signals could be 'pending' such that an awoken thread that receives a signal wont go to sleep again (that turn).

So I basically can't do it like this unless I use a lock in the producer?

Comment: I think you can do it in your case because your queue is, as you said, lockless, Just add a predicate that checks your lockless queue for the wait, and of course make sure that consumer owns the mutex before dropping into that wait. Your situation is a little different than traditional cv-mtx work because that queue is lockless. The producer need not latch the mutex before appending the queue in your case, but is is *critical* he append to the queue *before* issuing the `cv.notify_one()`. And if you spin up more than one consumer, you need `notify_all`.

Answer (score 2):

*Semaphores* and *Condition Variables* are somehow similar concepts. At least classical *Counting Semaphores* aren't available natively from the current c++ standard library. But these can be easily replaced with a [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) controlling an in-/decremented integer value.

The `std::mutex` for the condition variable is necessary, to protect from race conditions when changing the underlying value.